# i want to display the list of django many to many field not query set

Tags: django-queryset, manytomanyfield

i want to have the list of many to many field

this is my model

```
    class ElectionType(models.Model): 
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

    class Election Name(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        types = models.ManyToManyField(ElectionType)
```

view

```
    def ElectionType(request):
        ElectionType = ElectionName.objects.all()
        context = {'election_type': election_type}
```

type.types is returning ElectionType.None

```
{% for type in election_type %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ type.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ type.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ type.types }}</td>
    <tr>
```

Comment: Iterate over it: `{% for item in type.types.all %} {{ item.name }} {% endfor %}`.

Comment: multiple lists value are returned in different table how do i go about that?